# sendmail with zip is corrupting first file in the zip

Tags: unix, sendmail, mime, rhel

I am trying to send a mail with zip file attached from an unix box. I am limited to use sendmail utility. i ziped the files using the command

```
zip test.zip 1.html 2.html 3.html
```

and when trying to send mail with below commands. One of the three files (first file) is not opening properly. but the rest 2.html and 3.html is working fine.
I am getting the error as "Unavailable Data: 1.html"

```
(
echo "From: from@from.com"
echo "To: to@to.com"
echo "Subject: subject"
echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="X12345"'
echo '--X12345'
echo "Content-Type: application/zip;"
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
echo "Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=test.zip"
base64  test.zip
echo '--X12345'
) | sendmail -t
```

Can some please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt it's causing your problem, but you misspelled "attachment" in the Content-Disposition header. Looking at the spec, you may also need an empty line before the start of the base64 data, but I'm no expert, and I doubt it's causing your problem if the zip file itself arrives okay. (Can you definitely unzip the test.zip successfully locally before you send it?)

Comment: it worked.  thanks for quick help adding an empty line before base64 helped.

Comment: Also.. it did work with misspelled word.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to provide empty line to mark end of main headers and end of mime part header.

```
(
cat - <<END
From: from@from.com
To: to@to.com
ubject: subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="X12345"

--X12345
Content-Type: application/zip;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=test.zip

END
base64  test.zip
echo '--X12345'
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```